# Sample Application for WebView2 Older version

Tags: c++, webview2

I am working on official released version of Edge - 83.0.478.50( assuming this is latest official version) and its compatible Webview2 SDK version V0.9.430.

I could not find the sample application or Getting Started application. The official page is pointing to latest SDK API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32

I tried to build getting started application from https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/WebView2APISample and microsoft documentation page. But couldn't build application.

Does anyone has sample/Getting started application for V0.9.430 webview2 SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the [history of the WebView2APISample.vcxproj file](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/commits/master/WebView2APISample/WebView2APISample.vcxproj), you can see when it was updated to different WebView2 SDK versions and then checkout the corresponding change in your local repo.

Looks like [this change](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/commit/b34a0fe9a5caec8f88eb892d42b864f52f45ca1d#diff-56b68d72e9d7030e184f275b5f6fc61b) moved to build 430. If you have a local clone of the repo you should be able to do the following to get the source of the sample app at that time:

> `git checkout b34a0fe9a5caec8f88eb892d42b864f52f45ca1d`

We should probably make this easier with branches to label the different versions or something.

FYI, there have been various breaking changes to the WebView2 API since 430.

Comment: Looking forward to the Edge redistributable :D Any idea how big it's likely to be? Even just roughly?

Comment: That question came up previously on the [Feedback GH](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/194), something like 250MB compressed and 500MB uncompressed maybe.

Also the docs on the [fixed versioning feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution).